# Can you have an array of maps in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, maps

If so how? Because currently trying to handle input for multiple players using a map of actions.

Comment: `std::map<K,V> m[SIZE]` or `std::vector<std::Map<K, V> >`?

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector<std::map<a,b> >`

or if you want to handle the construction/destruction yourself

`std::vector<std::map<a,b>* >`

where a and b are the keys/values in your map

For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::vector<std::map<int,int>> vecOfMaps;
   std::vector<std::map<int,int>*> vecOfMaps2;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's with the mismatched angle brackets/parentheses?

Comment: And `"stdafx.h"` o_O.  And non-standard `main` definition.

Comment: Indeed, there are quite a few problems with the given code. Still, the approach is valid. It's not quite an array, though.

Comment: Sorry chaps - cut n paste from visual studio. OK now. Apologies.

Comment: Would I just make an iterator to access the map?

Comment: Why would you want the vector of pointers? So that pointers in the middle can be NULL? You can "handle construction/destruction" by using `insert` and `erase` (and variations).

Comment: @Camron: you can access the map using an interator or `operator[]`, for example: `vecOfMaps.push_back(std::map<int,int>()); vecOfMaps[0][23] = 47; std::map<int,int>::const_iterator i = vecOfMaps[0].find(23);`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, because if you don't store pointers, having to resize the vector will be an extremely costly operation. All the maps will have to be copied. Containers inside containers are an easy way to kill performance of even simple applications.

Comment: @edA: So, use smart pointers, or C++11 which eliminates the problem via `move`. Premature optimization isn't worth risking correctness. And for most applications `reserve` will fix performance handily.

Comment: I don't consider *functioning at a reasonable speed* part of *premature optimization*. But yes, smart pointers are usually a better option. Move semantics are great, but there's no requirement for STL to be implemented with them, is there?